# How to generate doctype XML file on XSLT

Tags: xml, vba, excel, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

I need to convert XML format into doctype XML format with the help of XSLT FILE. Source file is normal XML.

As per my targeted file I need to get:

`<!DOCTYPE Pip3B3ShipmentStatusNotification SYSTEM "3B3_MS_R01_00_ShipmentStatusNotification.dtd">`

My xslt code is given below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:transform version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output doctype-system="3B3_MS_R01_00_ShipmentStatusNotification.dtd" encoding="UTF-8"  indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Pip3B3ShipmentStatusNotification>
            <fromRole>
                <PartnerRoleDescription>
                    <ContactInformation>
                        <contactName>
                        </contactName>
                    </ContactInformation>
                </PartnerRoleDescription>
            </fromRole>
        </Pip3B3ShipmentStatusNotification>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

My macro given below, please check macro and let me know if it have any issue

```vb
Sub dummy()

    Call Transform("C:\Users\nypaul\Desktop\yves\out\source.xml", "C:\Users\nypaul\Desktop\yves\out\template\template.xsl", "C:\Users\nypaul\Desktop\yves\out\output.xml")

    MsgBox "ok"

End Sub

Function Transform(sourceFile, styleSheetFile, resultFile) As Boolean

    Dim Source As Object
    Dim StyleSheet As Object
    Dim Result As Object

    Set Source = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    Set StyleSheet = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    Set Result = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")

    On Error GoTo TheEnd

    Transform = True
    Source.async = False
    Source.Load sourceFile

    StyleSheet.async = False
    StyleSheet.Load styleSheetFile
    Source.transformNodeToObject StyleSheet, Result
    Result.Save resultFile
    Exit Function

TheEnd:
    Transform = False

End Function
```

How can I understand what is the error?

Comment: try `<xsl:output doctype-system="3B3_MS_R01_00_ShipmentStatusNotification.dtd"/>`

Comment: i tried that but not working

Comment: Please see this (http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nc4NzQ2)

Comment: Please provide the relevant parts of your XSL stylesheet.

Comment: @potame check it now

Comment: Well, that seems to work properly : http://xsltransform.net/jxN8Nq6. Please explain what's wrong for you, what's your ouput? What XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: @potame i am using one more macro to call the source file and template to make output please help me to understand if it have any issue

Comment: Side note: MSXML2 does not support XSLT 2.0.

Comment: @DanielHaley : Thanks for your important note. help me to understand what i have change instead of MSXML2

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you do

```
Source.transformNodeToObject StyleSheet, Result
Result.Save resultFile
```

the serialization of the result tree is being done by the Result.Save operation, not by the XSLT transformation, and therefore it is being done without any knowledge of the xsl:output declaration. This is because Result is a DOM Document object, so the XSLT processor merely creates a DOM, which does not involve serialization.

I'm not an expert in this particular transformation API but I think if you supply a Stream as the second argument of transformNodeToObject then it should work.